# Randomize and output list of items to text file

Tags: c++, arrays, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++

I'm a little stuck with a project I have. I'm supposed to take a list of words using char *, have the user enter how many words they want, randomize that number of words and then output to a text file.

Essentially I would want it to do this:

1. Read list of words
2. How many words do you want? (ex: 50)
3. Take (50) words randomly from that list
4. Output to text file

My list is something like this:

```
char * words [] =
{
    "Pistachio",
    "Avocado",
    "Salami",
    "Bologna",
};
```

And the list goes on....

I've used this to determine the number of elements in the array:

```
int array_size = sizeof ( words ) / sizeof ( words [0] );
```

and applying it to this:

```
cout << words[rand()%26] << endl;
```

I already have it set so that the user can tell the program how many words they want but I can't get it to choose that number and apply it to the list. Everything I've tried so far as either ended up in only one random word output to text. I'm really bad at using the random function, I don't think I'm using it properly at all! Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Could you show how you've tried to use the random function?

Comment: int i = rand() % 26; - was the one the project said to use but I can't see how to apply it to the program. I haven't tried 'srand' though. I'm still digging around, trying a few more things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the srand and rand function to generater number.
1. set the seed by srand(time(NULL));
2. get the random number = rand%50+1 (max count).

Comment: The thing is though, that I'm using char and not string, which is probably where I'm having the most trouble.

Comment: @Hydlide: Why **would** you use `char` and not `std::string`? Do you have too much time that needs wasting?

Comment: @KerrekSB I know, I know. It's a rule of the assignment though. I don't really understand why. I might just convert it all to string and deal with the consequences. :P

Comment: @Hydlide: Then it's a stupid rule and a stupid assignment. :-) (And *you* failed to state in your question that you are working under artificial constraints. Please don't do that, because it wastes the time of people who think up proper solutions to your problem.)

Comment: You're right. I'm kind of new to C++ though so I don't know about the number of differences between `char` and `string`. I feel like I haven't gotten enough info from the teacher at all so I guess I'll need to email him. I am thinking about just converting this all to `string` though and not even worrying about it because it seems much easier.